# What does G2 (chapter title) refer to in Death by Meeting?

Tags: abbreviations, acronyms, sports

In *Death by Meeting*, by Patrick Lencioni (the book is about leadership), There is a chapter entitled "G2." Since it is the title, there is not enough context for me to figure out its meaning, that is, what could it refer to and how it is related to the content of that chapter. I guess it has something to do with sports since the book uses massive sports (golf,baseball, basketball, football) references, but I have not found anything useful so far.

The chapter narrates a phone call between Will, who is kind of a consultant, trying to make the company's (Yip's) meetings more effective, and his friend Maddie, "an administrative assistant to one of
Playsoft’s other division heads." Playsoft is the parent company. There's been a merger (Yip is part of Playsoft now) and Will wants to know more about J.T., the man in charge of M&A. J.T is trying to put pressure on Casey, Yip's CEO, and make him resign, while Will is trying to save Casey through improving his and Yip's performance.

The chapter before "G2" is entitled "Out of the Bag," and the one after it, "The Monthly Strategic," which is the name that the author has chosen for one of the four types of meetings he suggests in the book.

Other chapter titles are: Mining, The Hook, No Prisoners, Light Bulb, Detention, Coming Clean, Bad Sequel, Wet Feet, On The Table, Smoking Gun, Fireworks, etc.

Comment: Best not to worry about something that doesn't add up.

Comment: In some countries G2 refers to Intel staff. Or, it might be a reference to world summits like G7...who knows? This might  be better suited to Literature.SE.

Comment: What are the other chapter names? Occasionally G2 is used out of context to refer to brains or intelligence (see comment above, or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staff_(military)#Continental_Staff_System).

Comment: G7 – meeting of seven cooperating nations. G2 – meeting of two merged companies.

Comment: @Cascabel , I think a combination of the two will make a lot of sense.

Comment: I am not sure if there can be a definitive answer to this...it might sound Primarily-Opinion-Based. If you want, and your Q does not generate VTC, I will post a fuller answer.

Comment: @Cascabel, Yes please, Thank you!

Comment: @Davo The chapter before "G2" is entitled "Out of the Bag," and the one after it, "The Monthly Strategic," which is the name that the author has chosen for one of the four types of meetings he suggests in the book.Other chapter titles are: Mining, The Hook, No Prisoners, Light Bulb, Detention, Coming Clean, Bad Sequel, Wet Feet, On The Table, Smoking Gun, Fireworks, etc.

Comment: Some of the names of those chapters  have geo-political or military aspects to them. Now I'm getting hyped, but I am still worried that this will get VTCed for POB or LitCrit. I will start on a possible A.

Comment: Have you read chapter G2? You might find that the term us defined within it. The other chapter headings look as though you aren't supposed to know the definitions until you've read the chapter.

Comment: Yes, I have. 3 times. There were no references to "g2" that I'm aware of. I explained its content as best as I could.  And you're right; (I don't know the exact term, but) the titles are kind of creative, and supposedly capture the essence of the chapters. I wanted to know what "g2" could possibly mean, and I think the idea that it could refer to summits like G7,and also intelligence (seeking and gathering information about an enemy or a rival,) is pretty much useful. I'm almost satisfied with the answers in the comments. Shall I close the Q? I'm not quite familiar with forum rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that  the acronym G2 (as the title of a chapter)  may have several interpretations, depending  on the context of the chapter. I see  multiple  meanings which could be puns.

In many countries, [G2 is the designation of the Intel staff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-2_%28intelligence%29), used to disguise its purpose. The system comes from the pre-WW II [US MI staffing designation.]

It was later adopted by many other countries whose military forces had been  trained by American “advisors” in the 1950s. (1)

As far as I know, the usage was still current up until 2014 in the USA.

So we have:

***G2 = Military intelligence***

From this, we have from modern slang an interpretation of the acronym to mean *intelligence* in a broader sense.

> In depth information about any person or thing;

[Urban Dictionary.](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=G2)  (sorry)

...from that, we can derive:

***G2 = Deep dark intel on a person.*** This is tricky, as it often means digital hacks.

And then, there is  G-two , which implies G, *plus a number*.

Most economic summits conducted which include the most important world leaders have a similar designation.

> The Group of Seven (G7) is an international intergovernmental economic organization consisting of seven major developed countries: Canada, France, Germany, Italy, Japan, the United Kingdom and the United States, which are the largest IMF-advanced economies in the world.

I think it was once G8, including Russia, but , well, politics.

***G7 = a summit***

So to me, this looks like an allusion to 2 different (maybe 3) ideas.

As it was a summit of two merging groups, and the merger was dependent on knowledge of the joining groups...I would say:

> **It is a play on the idea of G7 as a summit, and G2 referring to intel on an opposing force.**

---

Answer (score 0):

There is a Management Advice Website that is quite well known and covers topics that are likely mentioned in Lencioni's books:

G2 Community

> Interested in engaging with the team at G2? We’re always looking for experts to contribute to our Learning Hub in a variety of ways. Check it out and get in touch!

https://learn.g2.com/collaboration-quotes (Note the quote by Lencioni.)